# Fiddler - Change image within html response

Tags: fiddler

I have a html page which also has img1. So, there is only one request made when that page is loaded and this page fetches image1 from another server and render page.

So, in html response, i would like to change image with some other image.

Please let know if this can be achieved via fiddler ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by using auto responder feature.